# Android Retrofit NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, retrofit

my problem is, that I always get a nullpointerexception in my retrofit request, but I have no idea why...

`Feed`is a own created class which should contain the response from the retrofit request.

ServiceAPI:

```
@GET("top-headlines?country=de&apiKey=xxx")
Call<Feed> getNewsFeed();
```

Retrofit-Call in `onCreateView`:

```
Retrofit retrofitNewsData = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(NetworkService.NEWS_DATA_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Log.d(TAG, "network service connected to: " + retrofitNewsData);

    ServiceRepository serviceRepositoryNewsData = retrofitNewsData.create(ServiceRepository.class);

    Call<Feed> callNews = serviceRepositoryNewsData.getNewsFeed();
    callNews.enqueue(new Callback<Feed>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Feed> call, Response<Feed> response) {
             newsFeed = response.body();
            Log.d(TAG, "Habe den feed: " + newsFeed + " erhalten." + response.code());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Feed> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });`
```

Base-URL:
`public static final String NEWS_DATA_BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/v2/";`

Comment: Which line is throwing the NPE? `response.body()`?

Comment: No the problem occures a few lines after I initialize the newFeed object. 
Sry for the bad format, but:

HSNewsAdapter hsNewsAdapter = new HSNewsAdapter(newsFeed.getArticles());
allNews.setAdapter(hsNewsAdapter);

(allNews is a object of type recyclerview)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a another type. If your body can be empty you should to use Response, and parse response body.

Comment: How do you mean that? Can you give ma a short example?